# ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR Ajax .net web api

Tags: jquery, ajax, azure, ssl, iis

Running into a very strange error when trying to execute Ajax calls to a .NET Web Api hosted on IIS on Azure.

I've got my SSL cert from let's encrypt, it's applied to the website properly.  When I try to execute an ajax call I get:

*net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR*

If Fiddler is open, all works properly.  With Fiddler closed, we get the error.  Regular old HTTP works just fine.

Comment: David, did you figure this out?  Having the exact same issue.  .Net WebAPI hosted in Azure.  suddenly started happening in our production system with no changes to app or hosting.

Comment: It was a JavaScript syntax error - double check the syntax of your Auth header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for me was that Chrome was being strict on the format for the Authorization header.

The format of the header is **scheme token**, and its important that you *don't include a colon after the scheme*. My older style code had the format `Bearer: thetoken`, which was failing. I changed it to `Bearer thetoken` and now everything is working correctly.

```
headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was that I was sending an empty Authorization header.

The login to my app (an AngularJS SPA) sends a username/password in a JSON object, and if the login is valid then a JWT is returned which is then used for the Authorization header - e.g. Bearer {JWT} for future API requests.

Not sending an Authorization header when there was nothing to send fixed the issue.

Comment: This was the exact issue we were having with web API. The weird part is that it was only happening on some servers and not others. We were able to solve our problem with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  The fix in my case was updating the Authorization header to not include a JSON object when making the API call. Probably something I shouldn't have done in the first place.  ;-)

Example

```
headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  In my case, it happened because the API failed to get a connection to SQL Server (because I had stopped the service and forgot to restart it.)  Duh on me, but still, a more relevant error message would've made the problem obvious in one second...instead of many minutes :-|